# Analyser not updating canvas draws as quickly as audio is coming in

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

Whenever I have a new buffer that come into my client I want to redraw that instance of audio onto my canvas. I took the sample code from http://webaudioapi.com/samples/visualizer/ and tried to alter it to fit my needs in a live environment. I seem to have something working because I do see the canvas updating when I call .draw() but it's not nearly as fast as it should be. I'm probably seeing about 1 fps as it is. How do I speed up my fps and still call draw for each instance of a new buffer?

Entire code:
https://github.com/grkblood13/web-audio-stream/tree/master/visualizer

Here's the portion calling .draw() for every buffer:

```
function playBuffer(audio, sampleRate) {
    var source      = context.createBufferSource();
    var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, audio.length , sampleRate);
    source.buffer   = audioBuffer;
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio);

    source.connect(analyser);
    var visualizer = new Visualizer(analyser);
    visualizer.analyser.connect(context.destination);
    visualizer.draw(); // Draw new canvas for every new set of data

    if (nextTime == 0) {
        nextTime = context.currentTime + 0.05;  /// add 50ms latency to work well across systems - tune this if you like
    }
    source.start(nextTime);

    nextTime+=source.buffer.duration; // Make the next buffer wait the length of the last buffer before being played
}
```

And here's the .draw() method:

```
Visualizer.prototype.draw = function() {
    function myDraw() {
        this.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = SMOOTHING;
        this.analyser.fftSize = FFT_SIZE;

        // Get the frequency data from the currently playing music
        this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.freqs);
        this.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.times);

        var width = Math.floor(1/this.freqs.length, 10);

        // Draw the time domain chart.
        this.drawContext.fillStyle = 'black';
        this.drawContext.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++) {
            var value = this.times[i];
            var percent = value / 256;
            var height = HEIGHT * percent;
            var offset = HEIGHT - height - 1;
            var barWidth = WIDTH/this.analyser.frequencyBinCount;
            this.drawContext.fillStyle = 'green';
            this.drawContext.fillRect(i * barWidth, offset, 1, 2);
        }
    }
    requestAnimFrame(myDraw.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a working demo? as you can easily debug this using the Timeline in chrome. You can find out what process takes long. Also please take unnecessary math out. Most of your code doesn't need to be executed every frame. Also, how many times is the draw function called from `playBuffer`? When you call play, on the end of that function it requests a new animation frame. If you call play every time you get a buffer, you get much more cycles of `math->drawing->request frame`. This also makes it very slow. If you are already using the requestanimationframe, you shall only call the play function once.

To fix up the multi frame issue:

```
window.animframe = requestAnimFrame(myDraw.bind(this));
```

And on your playBuffer:

```
if(!animframe) visualizer.draw();
```

This makes sure it only executes the play function when there is no request.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a live example demo?  I'd like to run it through some profiling.  You're trying to get updates for the playing audio, not just once per chunk, right?

I see a number of inefficiencies:

- you're copying the data at least once more than necessary - you should have your scheduleBuffers() method create an AudioBuffer of the appropriate length, rather than an array that then needs to be converted.
- If I understand your code logic, it's going to create a new Visualizer for every incoming chunk, although they use the same Analyser.  I'm not sure you really want a new Visualizer every time - in fact, I think you probably don't.

-You're using a pretty big fftSize, which might be desirable for a frequency analysis, but at 2048/44100 you're sampling more than you need. Minor point, though.

-I'm not sure why you're doing a getByteFrequencyData at all.

-I think the extra closure may be causing memory leakage.  This is one of the reasons I'd like to run it through the dev tools.

-You should move the barWidth definition outside of the loop, along with the snippet length:

```
var snippetLength = this.analyser.frequencyBinCount;
var barWidth = WIDTH/snippetLength;
```

if you can post a live demo that shows the 1fps behavior, or send an URL to me privately (cwilso at google or gmail), I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: The question you asked about the once per chunk and a demo got me to rethink what I'm actually trying to do here. As the code is written I'm using PCM audio for local testing. Because of this, my chunks are very short so 'once per chunk' is what I was trying to do. If I were to setup a live demo I would have to add compression and my chunks would then become longer. Then, the 'once per chunk' idea wouldn't be suitable as I would then still only be getting 1 fps since a chunk would be about 1 sec in length. What I need is a slider that changes the refresh rate, independent of the chunk size.